# How to access parent object's parent from an object efficiently?

Tags: c++, architecture, game-engine, hierarchy

Sorry for the badly defined title. What I mean:

(Btw I am working on a game engine, and A is the **Scene**, B are the **Game Objects** and C are the **Components**)

**I have 3 classes: A, B, C**

- A contains B, and B contains C.
- A and B has a reference to each other.
- B and C has a reference to each other.

(A is forward declarated in B's header, and included in B's implementation)

It's like this: A <-> B <-> C

**My situation is this:**

- I want to use A's method from C. (Like telling the main container to add another B, etc)
- ~I want to make a reusable function which calls a method at the parent object's parent.
- For example in C's derived classes I don't have to care how C reaches A, I just call C's Reach-A-and-do-something method.

**My question is that which one should I use and why (or is there a better one?):**

- In C: GetB().GetA().DoSomething()
- C's DoSomething() calls B's DoSomething() which calls A's DoSomething.

The first one looks nicer to me, but in C's implementation i only include B's header, where **A is only forward declarated**. So **I can't use A's methods** without explicitly including it in C. (Is this a bad practice, or should I just include it?)

The second one **has a big overhead**. If I want to use A's XY method, I have to create an XY method in B which calls A's XY and I have to create an XY method in C which calls B's XY.

So I don't know how should I reach higher elements in the hierarchy from the lower elements.

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: Does adding the header file for A in the C file cause conflicts?

Comment: `GetB().GetA().DoSomething()` seems better. You can include A in C, just ensure that your definitions and declarations are separated and included. Another option might be to use `std::functional` and then initialize B with a function from A and copy it also to a `std::functional` variable in C so that C can then just call `my_std_functional()` which does something in A.

Comment: It works fine. Could you give me more details about "definitions and declarations are separated and included"?
If every class is in a different scope, then that's no problem, isn't it?

Comment: @Muscampester And is the second one better when I only want to use only one A method and A's header is big? Or I should always avoid the the second one?

Comment: I would say it is up to you. Both are feasible. Maybe with a minimal example  of what you are trying to do it would be easier to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Well, this is a very minimal example: Engine has a GraphicsSystem and a Scene. Scene has GameObjects, GameObjects have Components. 
When a GameObject is created, its Renderer component's pointer should be sent to GraphicsSystem.

Comment: Currently this is what I do: At GameObject's constructor, I call the Scene's AddRenderer method, which calls the Engine's AddRenderer method which calls the GraphicsSystem's AddRenderer Method.
A bit better would be that when I create a GameObject with the Scene's method, there I would Get the Renderer, and then proceed with the forwarding algorhythm mentioned before, but without 1 step.

Comment: Or an even better: in the Scene's AddGameObject method, I would just GetEngine().GetGraphicsSystem().AddRenderer()
So I have to include the graphics system only in the scene, and not in the game objects. But this makes extra dependencies which aren't so good.
With chain-calling the Scene would be only dependent on Engine, but now it is also dependent on GraphicsSystem.

Comment: Just for the record: keep the "law of demeter" in mind. Having knowledge about classes that are "two hops" away is seen as bad practice.

Comment: Yes, that's what frustrating me. Does "chain-calling" A->B->C is considered having knowledge? I think it's not, because A gives all responsibility to B and doesn't know about a C which makes nearly all the work. But is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In C: GetB().GetA().DoSomething()
>
> C's DoSomething() calls B's
> DoSomething() which calls A's DoSomething.

I think both are wrong because from architectural standpoint such approach creates strong coupling between the classes. Consider using event dispatcher, that implements the [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern for your logic. Let components send events to each other as well as react to them.

I am not sure about how will this work performance-wise in your case, but I strongly advise against [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) unless it's evident.

Comment: Currently I can only implement this, with storing all the other gameobjects in every gameobject. So every gameobject can reach (notify) every gameobject. But in my architecture the gameobjects are stored in one place (the scene) that's why gameobjects access the scene. (so with accessing the scene they can access other gameobjects, and notify them. )